error: Scenario Outline '...' has no examples defined
After updating SpecFlow nuget packages, I started getting this error for some scenarios. For example, for this:
Scenario Outline: Scenario1
Given Step1
When Step2
Then Condition1

I would get
error : (135:1): Scenario Outline 'Scenario1' has no examples defined


Turns out changing Scenario Outline to just Scenario fixes the issue.
Scenario: Scenario1
Given Step1
When Step2
Then Condition1

I guess in the past SpecFlow allowed you to use the Scenario Outline keyword even if no Examples are specified, but they've changed that in more recent version.s

I've been using SpecFlow for a decade, and I don't recall ever being able to use Scenario Outline without an examples table. Recently SpecFlow started supporting an examples table with a plain old Scenario, which is what you might be thinking about. It threw me for a loop a little bit.
